# why git returns this error message: "error: branch '.*' not found."

Tags: git

I am trying to delete al merged branch, but I dont understand why I got this error message:

```
prompt> (master) $ git b
  4.0
  4.1
  4.2
  4.3
  4.4
* master
prompt> (master) $ git b --merged | grep -v '*' | xargs git branch -d
error: branch '4.0' not found.
error: branch '4.1' not found.
error: branch '4.2' not found.
error: branch '4.3' not found.
error: branch '4.4' not found.
prompt> (master) $
```

---

## edit

I've problems just because I've this configuration:

```
#~/.gitconfig
[alias]
    b = branch --color
```

This means that my real command is `git branch --color --merged | grep -v '*' | xargs git branch -d`

Comment: Why can't you it them one by one? why are you trying of search and show the deleted branches?

Comment: I tried the commands one by one,they all worked fine and later used your command too. Its working fine

Comment: I think I just have problem because of an alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git b --merged | grep -v '*' | xargs git branch -d
```

Here you are trying of search the branches and then you are trying to show the deleted branches?

so **deleted** branches are not found on  `xargs git branch -d`

**Updated :**

This worked fine for me.

```
git branch --merged | grep -v '*' | xargs git branch -d

Deleted branch b_01 (was b62ecb1).
Deleted branch b_02 (was b62ecb1).
```

Comment: "... trying to show the deleted branches", `git branch -d <branch-name>` delete a branch not shows the deleted branches

Comment: @sajibkhan Oh yes.. I thought xargs will take inputs and also display back. Thanks learnt something here.

Comment: As a general rule, scripts should not run "porcelain" commands like `git branch` but instead should use "plumbing" commands like `git for-each-ref`. However, you need a fairly new version of Git (2.7.0 or later) to use `git for-each-ref` for this case: you need one that supports `--merged`.